# Disassembling bytecode into opcodes across different EVM versions

Tags: ethereum, solidity, decompiling, opcode, evm

I need to disassemble bytecode into opcodes across different EVM versions, to make it agnostic to the EVM version used during compilation?

As the second best option - is there a disassembler, that allows you to specify the EVM version to use?
I did plenty of research online but haven't found anything like this.
I'm currently using evmdasm:
https://github.com/ethereum/evmdasm

But it was not updated for a long time, so, as an example of the problem - with the release of Shanghai, and the introduction of `PUSH0`, for contracts, compiled with Shanghai EVM version I have opcode `UNKNOWN_0x5f`(basically unrecognized opcode 0x5f), while same operation in contract compiled using Paris version, will look like `PUSH1 0x00`.

Unification example:
Pushing 0, to stack in contract, compiled, using `paris` evm version, will look like `PUSH1 0x00`.
If you compile the same contract, using `shanghai` evm version, it'll look like `PUSH0`.
What I want is for the disassembler to make those opcodes look the same.
In this specific case it is easily achievable by doing, something like:
`decompiled_code.replace('PUSH0', 'PUSH1 0x00')` to cast to paris implementation.

In other words:
`decompile(x_shanghai_compiled) == decompile(x_paris_deployed) == decompile(x_other_evm_compiled)`

Comment: It's open source software. If it's unmaintained maybe try to patch it yourself.

Comment: It's a good idea, but this is quite a bit of work, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so asking the community for help. 
The thing is that I don't only need to add changes specific to Shanghai(which is easy), but also add a ton of functionality, by collecting EVM versions changelog, and designing functionality to allow the selection of versions or unification of decompilations. 
If, I'll not get suggestions on existing tools - I'll likely do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested. I found an existing package, that allows you to select evm version to use during disassembling:
https://github.com/crytic/pyevmasm

This package also contains a nice changelog of EVM versions in their tests, which you can use to make unifications, in places it is possible :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Dedaub disassembler; it's pretty good and well-maintained.

https://library.dedaub.com/decompile

Comment: Thanks!
This is helpful but does not directly answer my question, unfortunately, so I can't mark it as an answer. 
I'll modify my question to make a bit more clear.
Dedaub does handle all the EVM versions properly but doesn't allow you to unify decompilation, or specify EVM version to cast it to.

Comment: Ok. Your edit made it clearer. Usually, a disassembler is not a tool for that.
Taking in account that EVM versions are backward compatible, you can try to disassemble the bytecode into some high-level language and compile it to the earliest evm version bytecode you need.

Comment: Thanks!
Decompilation to compilable code seems to not work like this(you can get yul-like or solidity-like, but not compilable code), but backward compatibility, so the option to cast everything to the same oldest version - is very nice to know.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any tool that operates on the assembly level and retrofits it to the previous evm version. Maybe this niche is not filled and it's a good tool to write on the etk https://github.com/quilt/etk base, for example